# Dealing with broken pipes in ssh X11 forwarding with an intensive numerical simulation

Tags: ssh, x11, java, gui

I have a hydrodynamic code I inherited that has a java gui. It is quite user friendly but it is a nightmare to run through ssh because when I do X11 forwarding, if the connection experiences problems the simulation crashes and stops (broken pipe) which is annoying. I want to be able to do this so that I can run my simulation in some computer grid.

Is there any creative fix to my situation? (beyond making the java code command-line based.)

Comment: Start a VNC session instead, and connect to that?

Comment: many similar posts get suggestions to use `xpra`, like "gnu screen" but for X11.